# What is a good data visualization library for iOS?

Tags: ios, visualization

Similar to an existing question [What is a good visualization library for creating state diagrams and animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426228/what-is-a-good-visualization-library-for-creating-state-diagrams-and-animations). I am looking for a library similar to Flare Prefuse that works on iOS. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/), [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), or [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) inside a [UIWebView](http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/).  Protovis is by the same author as Flare.  D3 is an offshoot of Protovis.  Below are some other questions that might be helpful depending on what you are doing:

[Is there a visualization framework like JUNG for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758625/is-there-a-visualization-framework-like-jung-for-ios)

[Node-based data visualization library in c or objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684086/node-based-data-visualization-library-in-c-or-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks, that isn't exactly what I want - but it seems it's probably the only way to do it rather than  rolling out my own.

Comment: Another option is to port one of these libraries to Objective C.

Comment: is CorePlot the only native iOS data visualization library still  as of 6/2013