# How to depict a radar chart in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm currently developing my iOS app and want to depict a graph whose shape is a circle like pie chart, but its radius is dependent on each specific values. Sorry I don't know what the name of such chart is, but I'm sure every sane baseball fans or any sports fans I think should have ever seen such chart. For example, if a team's batting average is the best in the league which consists of 5 teams, its radius is length 5 (or any other length proportional to the other values), and if the same team's earned runs average is fourth in the league, its length is 2, etc, etc... and then those points or "tips" are connected to each other within the chart, and finally the area of the connected figure is filled with any colors.

Sorry for the awful explanation (it's quite difficult for non-English native to explain it more clearly), but my question is, is it feasible to depict such graphs in iOS application? If it can be done in iOS app, how/what library do I use to plot such graphs?

I've read Core Graphics documentation as well as [CorePlot example page](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Example-Graphs) but I wasn't able to find any such charts in those pages. I don't like the idea of using D3 embedded in `UIWebView` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267215/what-is-a-good-data-visualization-library-for-ios) since it's slow due to network latency. I don't know any other libraries to be as flexible and versatile as the two libraries above.

I use iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1.

#### [Update]

It's not a bubble chart. Let me explain it a little bit more concretely. The chart is a hexagon if every component of a record or sample is the best among the other competing records or samples and the number of the component to be described is six. In other words, the length of the component from the origin is whatever the longest possible values. But if one component, say, stolen bases, is NOT the best in the samples - say, it's the second best -, then the length of the component from the origin is not the longest; it's the second longest among the samples. And once every components (6 in this case) is plotted on the graph, those plotted points are connected to each other, and it finally is filled with whatever colors to make it the "area" of the record. And then this might be repeated in other records or samples as well. But unlike the bubble chart, one graph is made of one record and six features (or columns or variables) in this case - not all records and one feature (actually, three, but only one is used to make a bubble) which it is in the case of the bubble chart. Hope you get it...

#### [Update 2]

I finally got such charts on the Internet! The chart is something like this:

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a [bubble chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_chart). You can make one with Core Plot using a scatter plot. Implement one of the following datasource methods to provide custom plot symbols. Use your data to determine the size of each symbol. They can be different shapes and have varying fills and border line styles, too.

```
-(NSArray *)symbolsForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

Comment: No, it's not a bubble chart. I update my main post. Sorry I haven't able to search for and get such charts - it's basically impossible to look for something of which I don't know about the name... Hope you'd get it...

Comment: Updated again with a link to the image.

Comment: That's a [radar chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart). Core Plot doesn't support that type of plot yet, but it would be fairly easy to draw it yourself in a custom view or Core Animation layer.